# Internet Explorer paragraph text styles not cascading

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a paragraph style applied to a wrapper, but in Internet Explorer (I'm testing with IE 11) the styles are not cascading.

My css is as follows:

```
.typo--paragraph p, .typo--paragraph {
      font-family: "Brown Regular", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-size: 0.813rem;
      line-height: 1.375rem;
      color: #7272f1;
      text-align: left; }
```

I cannot apply the .typo--paragraph class directly to the `<p>` tags in some cases, as the CMS has limitations. However, in cases when I do apply the style directly, it works fine.

The HTML follows this structure.

```
<div class="typo--paragraph">
  <p>Paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

It's working as expected in every other browser

Comment: The CMS must be overriding your style, try to use !important in your CSS. Maybe IE loads your CMS style after your own style, don't know works fine for me here https://jsfiddle.net/urd9myzv/, also in IE

Comment: @Mikey This doesn't seem to be the issue... When I'm inspecting in the Dev Tools, it doesn't show the correct styles at all, overridden or not. They're in the CSS file for sure, triple checked that. It's working in every other browser also. So it's very odd behaviour here.

Comment: Well, IE is very odd at times indeed.